# How to pause video after particular time and show alert you have to subscribe in HTML5 video tag?

Tags: button, input, html5-video, jbutton

Please suggest as all browsers are going to stop uses of Flash Player so any alternative please let me know rather than HTML5 video tag.

Comment: In the title you are asking how to do it with HTML5 video tag but in the question you are asking how to do it without, which one is it?

Comment: anything will work for me please let me know if you have idea about HTML5